# How to run `gprolog` under an Emacs sub-process shell?

Tags: shell, term, shell-mode

I'd like to run the [`gprolog`](http://www.gprolog.org) interactive interpreter in an Emacs sub-process shell (started with `M-x shell`).

The interactive interpret starts without a problem, but it does not respond to some keystrokes as expected.

---

To illustrate the problem, I first show a simple interaction as it occurs when I run `gprolog` in a "top-level shell" (i.e. not one running as a subprocess of Emacs).

(In the excerpts below, please regard the delimiters `<<` and `>>` as "markup" to indicate the text I type.  In the actual interaction, I don't type any `<<` or `>>` sequences.  Neither do I type the `▮` characters, which I'm using only to indicate the position of `point`.  *With the exception of the text enclosed by `<<`...`>>` and `▮`, all text shown in the excerpts below is produced by `gprolog`.*)

**Staring from top-level shell**

First I type the following query:

```
| ?- <<member(X, [a,b,c]).>>▮
```

Then I hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (shown below as `[RET]`):

```
| ?- <<member(X, [a,b,c]).[RET]>>

X = a ? ▮
```

Now I hit <kbd>;</kbd> once:

```
| ?- <<member(X, [a,b,c]).[RET]>>

X = a ? <<;>>

X = b ? ▮
```

Note that pressing `;` was all that I had to do to elicit the next response from `gprolog`.

Finally I hit <kbd>;</kbd> twice more, thereby exhausting the list of remaining results:

```
| ?- <<member(X, [a,b,c]).[RET]>>

X = a ? <<;>>

X = b ? <<;>>

X = c ? <<;>>

no
| ?- ▮
```

**Staring from Emacs sub-process shell**

Next I show what an attempt to run the same interaction in an instance of `gprolog` invoked from an Emacs sub-process shell.

Up to this point, it looks the same as before:

```
| ?- <<member(X, [a,b,c]).[RET]>>

X = a ? ▮
```

But now, if when I press `;`, the semicolon character gets inserted, but `gprolog` does not respond:

```
| ?- <<member(X, [a,b,c]).[RET]>>
X = a ? <<;>>▮
```

If now I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `gprolog` (basically) prints out one more result and terminates the query (prematurely):

```
| ?- <<member(X, [a,b,c]).[RET]>>

X = a ? <<;[RET]>>
;

X = b ? 

yes
| ?- ▮
```

---

I encountered a similar problem with `swipl` (Swiss-Prolog), but found that starting it with the `-tty` flag made it usable under an Emacs sub-process shell (though the interface behaves a little differently).

I did not find anything like `swipl`'s `-tty` flag for `gprolog`.

Comment: What about using `M-x run-prolog` instead of `M-x shell`?

Comment: @npostavs: That works very nicely, thank you.  I'll gladly accept it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to run an interactive prolog session under Emacs is to use `M-x run-prolog`.  It includes the code needed to send single characters at a time, rather than the line-based interaction of `M-x shell`.